# sbt stuck while downloading

Tags: scala, sbt

a couple days ago i started to learn scala. I want to use sbt for the dependency management but when i start sbt in my console it need round about 1h to resolving and downloading all dependencies.

My search at google was unsuccessfull so i hope somebody can help me to speed up sbt.

My build.sbt

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies ++= {
val akkaV = "2.3.5"
val sprayV = "1.3.1"
Seq(
    "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % sprayV,
    "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % sprayV,
    "io.spray" %% "spray-testkit" % sprayV % "test",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaV,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaV % "test",
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.3.11" % "test"
)
}
```

I use Mac OS X 10.8 with java 1.8.20

Greets

der commander

Comment: Slackware 14.1,  java 1.8.20, download in 30 sec. Check your network/proxy

Answer (score 6):

Hahaha welcome to sbt hell!! I find one trick is to interupt (ctrl + c) the process and restart it.  It somtimes seems to get stuck and needs a kick. It will pick up where it left off thanks to the cache.

Fortunately its usually only the first time you run it it takes that long. Until you change your dependencies that is!!

Answer (score 1):

it seems that i have a very slow connection to the maven central. After i change the default maven repository from the UK to France it needs only 3 minutes. I think this is ok for my internet connection and a clear start.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I "solved" my case by building on a remote machine with a fast network connection.