# sbt stuck at Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ... on Mac OS X Yosemite with Java 8 and scala 2.11.6

Tags: java, macos, sbt, osx-yosemite

All of my sbt commands (sbt assembly, sbt package etc..) get's stuck with following message

Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite, Java - 1.8.0_45, Scala - 2.11.6, Sbt - 0.13.8

Any idea why my sbt commands always stuck with above message?

Comment: did you try any other SBT version (like 0.13.5)?

Comment: Yes, tried 0.13.5. But getting same error. Is sbt compatible with java8? somehow i feed that might be the issue. But can't test with java7 as mac os x yosemite doesn't allow installing java7.

Comment: I have OS X with Yosemite and I am running java7. You could have multiple Java version and just change your `JAVA_HOME` to control which one to use. What is your `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: just checked on oracle site...java7 with update less than 25 has been disabled. So will try with latest update in java7. Btw any idea if this problem is specific to java8 or it could be any other issue?

Comment: Maybe you are referring to Java used by OS X. Maybe for security purposes they require you have Java 8 and patch it regularly. You can have Java 8 for OS X stuff and then use Java 7 for your projects (two different things). You might have to install it [manually](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) thought.

Comment: Finally I installed jdk7 update 80 and sbt has worked fine now. So it seems like the issue was with java8

Answer (score 1):

It seems that SBT still has issues with Java 8. I found these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25926111/1553233), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27660083/1553233) to be useful. Downgrading to Java 7 is a much safer choice for now.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes sbt stuck when downloading files. 
You can periodically check size  ~/.ivy2 folder and if size isn't grow kick sbt process and rerun sbt.

For me only after 5 kicks sbt download all files!!!

[sbt stuck while downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798460/sbt-stuck-while-downloading)